# Is it possible to create custom method for opening/closing forms?

Tags: c#, winforms

So i have these 3 buttons clicks.

```
private void btn_OpenNotePad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Hide();

    Form2 forma_NotePad = new Form2();
    forma_NotePad.ShowDialog();

    this.Close();
}

private void btn_OpenPaint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Hide();

    Form3 forma_Paint = new Form3();
    forma_Paint.ShowDialog();

    this.Close();
}

private void btn_ContactAdmin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Hide();

    Form4 forma_ContactAdmin = new Form4();
    forma_ContactAdmin.ShowDialog();

    this.Close();
}
```

They are all pretty similar so i thought about is it possible to create one method for them? Something like:

```
private void OpenForm(parameter1, parameter2)
{
    this.Hide();

    parameter1 parameter2 = new parameter1();
    parameter2.ShowDialog();

            this.Close();
}
```

So i can call them

```
OpenForm(parameter1,parameter2);
```

and make my code shorter and cleaner.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure you could refactor this functionality in a separate method:

```
private void btn_OpenNotePad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Open<Form2>();
}

private void btn_OpenPaint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Open<Form3>();
}

private void btn_ContactAdmin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Open<Form4>();
}

private void Open<TForm>() where TForm: Form, new()
{
    this.Hide();
    new TForm().ShowDialog();
    this.Close();
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Will accept your answer as soon as i can :)